# Android - How to post a comment using Facebook SDK 4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there any way to post a comment using FacebookSDK 4.0.1.
Because Request was removed in new SDK. 
Assume that I had login and got "publish_actions" permission.

```
private void facebookLogin() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("user_friends"));
}

private void facebookLogout (){
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}

private void facebookPost() {
    //check login
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (accessToken == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, ">>>" + "Signed Out");
        status = Status.POST;
        facebookLogin();
        return;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, ">>>" + "Signed In");
        status = Status.NONE;
    }
    if (accessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
        Log.d(TAG, ">>>" + "contain publish_actions");

        //I wanna post a comment in here
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, ">>>" + "NOT contain publish_actions");

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to comment or post a rich story? With taggable friends? You dont need the publish_actions permission this way.

Comment: I wanna to post on a comment, I also have comment ID . How can I do?

Comment: What are other types used other than "badge" with setPreviewPropertyName(...)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sharing using com.facebook.share.widget.ShareApi class

```
ShareApi.share(content,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to post something on a users wall, here are the steps you need to take in order to use Facebook Post, using `Open Graph Stories`

1) Head on to the [Developer Console](https://developers.facebook.com/)

2) Register your application, create the `new` login flow - be warned the older login flow does not work with SDK 4.0

3) Now once login is working for you, Head on to the Dashboard for this app, select Open Graph from the pane on left.

4) Define your Actions, Stories and Objects here.

5) Although Facebook has given an option to get code, next to the Stories, Action Types and Object Types - be warned this code is old and will not work.

Here is what works for me:

My app name is (as defined on the Dev Console)

friendssampleapp

My Action Type: Celebrating
My Object Type: Milestone

Here is the snippet of code I use to post via a button click:

```
            ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "friendsampleapp:milestone")
            .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
            .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
        //  .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
            .build();


            // Create an action
            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("friendsampleapp:celebrating")
            .putObject("milestone", object)
            .build();

            // Create the content
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("milestone")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

            ShareDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to use GraphRequest which is available in Facebook SDK 4.0

Comment: Sorry mate, in that case the above does not apply, I am not sure how to achieve what you are looking for. If I find anything relevant I will definitely post it here :)

Comment: What are other types used other than "badge" with setPreviewPropertyName(...)?

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("message", "This is a test message");

        new GraphRequest(
                accessToken,
                "/me/feed",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    }
                }
        ).executeAndWait();
```